# Find nearby places getting response from google api is, api key not uthorized

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I am getting my current location and then I have to find the restaurants present with respect to the radius, code is working fine. But having response from google api is,

```
{   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 49.248.59.224, with empty referer",   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

I have created Android key with enabled google place api, google maps api v2
still getting problem with this can anyone help me out please,
my code is below

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                sb.append("&radius=5000");
                sb.append("&types="+type);
                sb.append("&sensor=true");
                sb.append("&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Comment: During api key activation, have you selected 'Any IP allowed' option?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to register your `ip address` with the `api key` you have. Visit `developers console` and add a `public ip` for your `api key`.

Comment: Please can u tell me how to register public ip address is it necessary to pay registration fee?

Comment: @Vijay no need to pay registration fee, just leave "Allowed IPs" as blank as mentioned by Hardik

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/noxnowngtqxxhss/2015-08-04_16-15-32.png?dl=0
please refer to the dropbox link picture, here in "Edit Allowed IPs" leave it blank so it will allowed all ips address :)

Comment: Hey hardik !. that means i have to  create server key right ? for google place api

Comment: Yes you have to create server key. BTW which key are you using in "sb.append("&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");" ?

Comment: I am using server key  and selected all type ip's, but still not working and
getting message that "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 49.248.59.224, with empty referer."